# What would be XPath Expression for this to use with ImportXML in Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

Please see this url:
http://www.flipkart.com/intex-fitrist/p/itmeg62zxbnagp8h?pid=SBNEGGD7APTAZE2G

If you do a "View Source" for this, you will notice this text in the source:

```
FKART.product.pid = "SBNEGGD7APTAZE2G";
```

I am not able to figure out what would be the xpath expression for this that I can use with ImportXML in Google Sheets to extract this text. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the element that contains this text?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that the parameter your referring to is literally in the url itself, you can also grab it from the meta content or about 100 other fields.. here is one way:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("http://www.flipkart.com/intex-fitrist/p/itmeg62zxbnagp8h?pid=SBNEGGD7APTAZE2G","//meta[@name='twitter:app:url:googleplay']/@content"),"pid=(\w+)&")
```